# Why addition small number to float is wrong?

Tags: floating-point, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Addition of Double values inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903003/addition-of-double-values-inconsistent)

```
int x = 0;
float n = 0;
while ( n != 1 ) {
n += 0.1;
++x;
}
```

I wonder Why this loop is infinite?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Nice x-ref, @Neil, complete with links to, or copies of, the canonical works on the subject.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`0.1` cannot be represented exactly in floating-point:

```
printf("%.16f\n", 0.1f);
```

displays:

```
0.1000000014901161
```

So `n` will never be exactly equal to `1`.

As @sirlak says in comments below, it's almost *never* correct to test floating-point variables for equality like this.

Comment: Test for >= or <= with floating point numbers. Never test for strict equality, precisely because of this problem. If you need to test for equality, test a range, e.g. `(n > 0.99)&&(i < 1.01)`

Comment: @sirlark: "Never test for strict equality" isn't always valid advice, but it is *usually* the case.

Comment: Out of genuine curiosity, can you give me a case where you need to test for strict equality by value (as opposed to testing in some other way like pointer equality)

Comment: @sirlark: To be honest, I can't think of an example off the top of my head.  I guess my point was more that your rule should be closer to "Never test for strict equality unless you're sure that it's appropriate"!

Comment: The point is that "never test for equality" is close enough to true that you might as well adopt it as an absolute rule, both for correctness and to keep your code readable by others.