# Is Vb.Net Math Broken?

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, floating-point

While in middle of an execution,

I just opened the immediate window and i typed like this,

```
?1.66 + 0.83
```

so as a result of this expression the following was displayed,

```
2.4899999999999998
```

Actually that expression should have returned `2.49` but it is returned the same value with different floating points. What is wrong with this.?  Is there any work around available to fix this.? by the way i don't want to format the above value.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [floating point precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: [Is JavaScript floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1)

Comment: [Is double Multiplication Broken in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net) [odd math in actionscript 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784594/odd-math-in-actionscript-3]) [weird math calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771718/weird-math-calculation) [Why do I see a double variable initialized to some value like 21.4 as 21.399999618530273?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996)

Comment: [Why do floats seem to add incorrectly in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250097/is-vb-net-math-broken) [Floating point arithmetic not producing exact results in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java) --- You see, you're not the first one with this problem...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is just how floating numbers work. They work with some level of precision, when you write `1.66` it might actually be stored as `1.66000000000000000001` or `1.65999999999999999` in memory. So when you start adding these numbers together that small error adds up.

If you want to avoid this, you could use `System.Decimal` data type which will solve this issue most scenarios (it uses a different model to store the value in memory that preserves the exact value).

For example, try

```
?1.66D + 0.83D
```

`D` [suffix](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/08/secrets-and-lies-of-type-suffixes-in-c-and-vb-net/) means that the value is of type `Decimal`

Comment: This is better than many answers which say, without qualification, that `Decimal` is exact. But is “most scenarios” credible? Dividing a bill three ways? Compound interest? Scientific functions (log, sin)? Echo filter?

Comment: "This is just how floating pint numbers work" *because they are actually being converted to binary*

Answer (score 0):

The immediate window is displaying the value to decimal places, which is its default action, formatting needs to be applied if you want 2 decimal places, rounded up.

Comment: This just hides the problem and ignores the reason why the OP got 10 decimals instead of 2