# Float random(?!) precision quirk

Tags: python

I have just started learning python and I have stumbled across a particularity

python version:

> Python 2.7.2 (default, Jul 20 2011, 02:32:18) [GCC 4.2.1 (LLVM,
>   Emscripten 1.5, Empythoned)] on linux2

on:http://repl.it/languages/Python

Working with the interpreter assigning:

```
    pi = 3.141 // 3 places decimal precision
    #typing pi  & pressing return puts 3.141
   type(pi)
=> <type 'float'>
    pi = 3.1415
   type(pi)
=> <type 'float'>
    #pi puts 3.1415000000000002
```

Ok floating point precision is notorious for being unprecise;
**but why do only the 4 point precision get that "tail"?**

Also:

```
 pi2 = 3.1415100000000002
 pi == pi2 # pi was assigned 3.1415
 => True
 print(pi2)
 3.14151 # Where's my precision?
```

Comment: Not every decimal fraction can be precisely represented by a binary encoded float. For this reason, using `==` with floats is generally not a good idea. A much simpler case: `0.1 + 0.2` evaluates to `0.30000000000000004`. This is not loss of precision, this is a byproduct of encoding a decimal fraction in binary IEEE-754 format.

Comment: @android why does it cut my precise assignment?

Comment: If you want your precision, you can use `Decimal` module.

Comment: @raam86 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems. [This](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) might help.

Comment: @raam86 If you're still confused, read up on how to convert a fraction from decimal to binary and try doing this conversion by hand (on paper) for `0.1`. You'll see why.

Comment: @Zhenya I have actually searched a lot for it but didn't find something exactly like this, not python related anyway

Comment: This is by no means python-specific. I guess for any language X there are several questions about the floating-point. Python-related (first or second google hit): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594985/why-do-simple-math-operations-on-floating-point-return-unexpected-inacurate-re and many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers and floats are given a certain number of bits.  For integers, each bit corresponds to a power of two.  The first digit is 2<sup>0</sup>, then 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, and so on.  So to store the integer `5` we have **2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup>** = **1 + 4**.

For floating point numbers, we store them in two parts.  The exponent, and the decimal.  If we have an decimal of .75 and a exponent of 2, we do **.75 * 10<sup>2</sup>** = **7.5**.  The decimal is stored as negative powers of 2.  So we have 2<sup>-1</sup>, 2<sup>-2</sup>. 2<sup>-3</sup>. etc.  These equate to `.5`, `.25`, `.125`, etc.

Some numbers are impossible to store, because they literally require infinite bits to represent, like 0.1, and others like 3.1415 require more bits than the CPU provides for floating-point numbers (24 is standard for 32bit floats, but algorithms vary).

The correct way to compare floats is to have a variance defined, and use something along these lines.

```
variance = .0001
floatsEqual = lambda f1, f2: f1 - variance <= f2 and f1 + variance >= f2

if (floatsEqual(3.1415, 3.1415 + 1 - 1)):
    pass
```

In Python, the decimal library is also useful.