# Last decimals are random counting float

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I am starting with learning Python. I currently have the following small piece of code:

```
a = float(input())
b = float(3)
while a < b:
    print(a + 0.0001)
    a+=0.0001
```

This counts, but there appear decimals in the end of the float. Why do they come there and what are they?

Output:

[image]

Comment: Because computers don't store floats with perfect accuracy.

Comment: What makes you think they're random? Also, why include a *picture* of your output? Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1089018/3001761) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2986150/3001761) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1594985/3001761) or ...

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: It makes me sad that the accepted answer at the dupe Q is so poor

Answer (score 1):

This is because the numbers in the question are not exactly represented by binary floating point. Start with `0.0001`. The [closest double precision value](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.0001) is in fact:

```
0.00010000000000000000479217360238592959831294137984514236450195312 5
```

So when you write `0.0001` what you actually get is the number above. That is then added to whatever value you input, and then the result is the closest representable value to that.

If this comes as a shock to you, then I suggest that you read David Goldberg's timeless article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Can we have a few more decimal places in the value for `0.0001`, please?  (I get `0.000100000000000000004792173602385929598312941379845142364501953125`.)

Comment: @mark you are correct. I mis-copied the value from rob's page