# JavaScript How to calculate string value with 18 decimals

Tags: javascript

I'd like to calculate 1538422.986611792949856002 - 1

Expecting value is 1538421.986611792949856002 (showing 18 decimals is the point.)

I think I need to make those two numbers to string since functions such as parseFloat, Number don't show the 18 decimals and subtract those two strings??

**shortcut** Calculate string values but keep 18 decimals.

Comment: You may want to try out some [Big Decimal](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a help from Locutus which seeks to assimilate other languages’ standard libraries to JavaScript.

I used bcsub to calculate `1538422.986611792949856002 - 1`. The feature which is from php makes number to string so that we can avoid the floating-point problem in computer.

You can find more informations [here](https://locutus.io/php/bc/).

Answer (score 1):

```
eval("1538422.986611792949856002 - 1").toFixed(18)
```

Comment: I tried that in console.log and the output is 1538421.986611793050542474. not 1538421.986611792949856002. Why is that?

Comment: because of floating-point problem in computer.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963873/1-265-10000-126499-99999999999

Comment: Damn, There's no way to calculate to see the output 1538421.986611792949856002 then?? I don't want to use a library

Comment: No, you can't get the exact output you want but you can get approx output using 
Math.fround(eval("1538422.986611792949856002 - 1")).toFixed(18)

Comment: You can solve this problem by deviding the number in two part foloating part and not floating part. And perform opration between floating part of num1, num2 and non-floating part of num1, num2. Then concate the result.

Comment: You should show how to actually solve AND perhaps add all those comments to the answer.  As it stands without the comments it does not provide an accurate answer.