# Division in Java to get next upper value

Tags: java, division, integer-division

I am dividing two ints x/y,. Say 3/2. Then one would get 1 as result though the actual result is 1.5. Ok this is obvious as it's int division. But I want  1.5 to be rounded off to the next highest int not the immediate lowest. So  2 is desired as result. (One can write simple logic using mod and then division...  But am looking for simple Java based API). Any  thoughts?

Comment: why don't you simply add 1. ?

Comment: @Ravi, adding 1 will give an incorrect result if the division was 4 / 2.

Answer (score 4):

You can, in general, write `(x + y - 1) / y` to get the rounded-up version of `x/y`.  If it's `3/2`, then that becomes `(3 + 2 - 1) / 2 = 4 / 2 = 2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ceil (ceiling) function:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)

That will essentially round up to the nearest whole number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922779/ceil-not-working-as-i-expected

Comment: Then you simply cast one of hte integers to double (e.g.: (double)x/y)

Comment: Yes, that's fine too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the datatype to double, following is the best solution -

```
double x = 3;
double y = 2;        
Math.ceil(Math.abs(x/y));
```

This will give you 2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.Math;
//round Up   Math.ceil(double num)
//round Down Math.floor(double num)
public class RoundOff 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 { //since ceil() method takes double datatype value as an argument
   //either declare at least one of this variable as double
    int x=3; 
    int y=2; //double y =2;

   //or at least cast one of this variable as a (double) before taking division
    System.out.print(Math.ceil((double)x/y)); //prints 2.0
   //System.out.print(Math.ceil(x/y));
 }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are very seldom helpful. Please explain how your code answers the question. For us all to learn. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for suggestion I thought code is simple enough to be understood directly by looking at it ,as I have already shown the important thing through the comment.