# Precision problem with stringstream and double

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I see a double variable initialized to some value like 21.4 as 21.399999618530273?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-39999961)

Here is my code

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  if (ac > 1)
    {
      std::string input = av[1];
      std::stringstream ss;
      double output;
      ss << input;
      ss >> output;
      std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << output << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert a string to a double using stringstreams.

It works, but it acts very weirdly when using very big numbers:

```
./a.out 999999999999999999999999
999999999999999983222784.00

./a.out 42
42.00
```

How can i handle all double values?

Comment: How is this an exact duplicate? The other thread is about accuracy with recurring binary digits. This threads is about the limits of precision. It's subtly different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't handle "all double values" with arbitrary precision. In your case, you have about 15 decimal digits of precision. Write `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10` to the console and you'll see.

Take a read through [this guide to floating-point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).