# Append a digit in front of another digit between /s?

Tags: java, regex

I have a bunch of strings that looks like this

```
/files/etc/hosts/2/ipaddr
/files/etc/hosts/2/canonical
/files/etc/hosts/2/alias[1]
/files/etc/hosts/3/ipaddr
/files/etc/hosts/3/canonical
/files/etc/hosts/3/alias[1]
/files/etc/hosts/4/ipaddr
/files/etc/hosts/4/canonical
/files/etc/hosts/4/alias[1]
```

I would like to append a 0 in front of any digit that sits between the `/` and `/`.  After the append, the results should look like this...

```
/files/etc/hosts/02/ipaddr
/files/etc/hosts/02/canonical
/files/etc/hosts/02/alias[1]
/files/etc/hosts/03/ipaddr
/files/etc/hosts/03/canonical
/files/etc/hosts/03/alias[1]
/files/etc/hosts/04/ipaddr
/files/etc/hosts/04/canonical
/files/etc/hosts/04/alias[1]
```

I am pretty sure that I need to use a simple regular expression for searching.  I think `/\d*/` should be sufficient but I am not sure how to modify the string to insert the digit 0. Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13503345/2027196) for how to insert one string into another. Short answer - use StringBuilder.

regex's aside, would that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
newString = string.replaceAll("/(\\d)(?=/)", "/0$1");
```

`\\d` is only one digit. Feel free to use `\\d+` for one-or-more digits.

`$1` means the part of the string that matched first thing that appears in brackets (with some exceptions), thus `(\\d)`.

You need to use look-ahead `(?=...)` instead of just `/(\\d)/` because otherwise

```
/files/etc/hosts/3/5/canonical
```

will become

```
/files/etc/hosts/03/5/canonical
```

instead of

```
/files/etc/hosts/03/05/canonical
```

(the `/` between 3 and 5 will get consumed during matching the 3 if you don't use look-ahead, thus it won't match on the 5).

This is not an issue (and you can simply use `/(\\d)/`) if the above string is not a possible input.

[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: +1 for using look ahead to not consume possible adjacent match

Comment: Thank you very much!  I didn't know about the $1.  Learned something new everyday.