# Inserting Newline character before every number occurring in a string?

Tags: java

I have String of format something like this

```
String VIA = "1.NEW DELHI 2. Lucknow 3. Agra";
```

I want to insert a newline character before every digit occurring succeeded a dot so that it final string is like this

```
String VIA = "1.NEW DELHI " +"\n"+"2. Lucknow " +"\n"+"3. Agra";
```

How can I do it. I read Stringbuilder and String spilt, but now I am confused.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884353/insert-a-character-in-a-string-at-a-certain-position

Comment: I read that before adding the question. In that question you know where to place that specific character but in my problem I don't know where to place it.

Comment: @user2963317 Did you even look at my answer?

Comment: Yeah I am just looking at that now.

Comment: @user2963317 My answer should only look for digits followed by dots

Comment: @user2963317 Please put a check mark (on the left side of my answer) if you found it useful and at the same time upvote it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String[] splits = VIA.split("\d+\.+");
for(String split : splits){
   builder.append(split).append("\n");
}

String output = builder.toString().trim();
```

Comment: there is a slight change in my problem

I want to insert newline after number succeeding by '.'

like 1. and 2. and 3.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way here to do that would be go in a for loop and check if the char is a     isDigit() and then adding a '\n' before adding it to the return String. Please note, I am not sure if you want to put a '\n' before the first digit.

```
String temp = "";
for(int i=0; i<VIA.length(); i++) {
  if(Character.isDigit(VIA.charAt(i)))
    temp += "\n" + VIA.charAt(i);
  } else {
    temp += VIA.charAt(i);
  }
}
VIA = temp;
//just use i=1 here of you want to skip the first charachter or better do a boolean check for first digit.
```

Comment: No not before the first digit. And even though it places I don't have a problem with that.

Comment: @user2963317 If you are satisfied with the answer can you please upvote my answer, thanks.

Comment: error

cannot invoke Isdigit on primitive type char.

Comment: My bad, you will have to use it like this Character.isDigit(VIA.charAt(i))