# How to split a string in Java at a particular index?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a method that takes in a string.

- If it has three characters, then I put a `:` in between the zeroth and first element.
  Example: `123` → `1:23`
- If it has four characters, then I put a `:` in between the first and and second element.
  Example: `1234` → `12:34`

For some reason, I keep getting odd results.

Here is my method:

```
private String addColon(String openOrclose)
{
    String newHour = null;
    if(openOrclose.length() == 3)
    {
        newHour = openOrclose.substring(0,0) + ":" + openOrclose.substring(1,2);

    }
    else
    {
        newHour = openOrclose.substring(0,1) + ":" + openOrclose.substring(2,3);
    }
    return newHour;
}
```

For three characters, my result is `:2`, and for four characters, my result is `1:3`.

Comment: this is not going to work `substring(0,0)`  The javadocs state *endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.*

Comment: i tried substring(0), and that didnt work either

Comment: try `substring(0,1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. You need to adjust the indicies for the substring calls:

```
private String addColon(String openOrclose)
{
    String newHour = null;
    if(openOrclose.length() == 3)
    {
        newHour = openOrclose.substring(0,1) + ":" + openOrclose.substring(1,3);

    }
    else
    {
        newHour = openOrclose.substring(0,2) + ":" + openOrclose.substring(2,4);
    }
    return newHour;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems very much related to this question [Insert a character in a string at a certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884353/insert-a-character-in-a-string-at-a-certain-position)

Note: I would have just commented this under your question but I have 49 reputation and need 1 more point to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the indexes that you're passing into `substring()`:

```
private String addColon(String openOrclose)
    {
        String newHour = null;
        if(openOrclose.length() == 3)
        {
            newHour = openOrclose.substring(0,1) + ":" + openOrclose.substring(1,openOrclose.length());

        }
        else if(openOrclose.length() == 4)
        {
            newHour = openOrclose.substring(0,2) + ":" + openOrclose.substring(2,openOrclose.length());
        }
        return newHour;
    }
```

Quoted from the Java Doc:

> Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex. Examples:
>
> "hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"  "smiles".substring(1, 5)
>   returns "mile"