# How Do I Concatenate Characters to the Beginning of a String?

Tags: java

I have the following statement: `binaryOutput = y % 2 + binaryOutput;`

I want to the value of `y % 2` to be added at the very beginning of `binaryOutput`. Is there a better way to do this operation than the way I did it? I feel like my method is a little redundant.

Edit: `binaryOutput` is a String object. `y` is an integer.

Comment: What type is `binaryOutput` and `y`?

Comment: If you are building a string in a loop then using `StringBuilder` will be more efficient (but your code will not be shorter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a character in a string at a certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884353/insert-a-character-in-a-string-at-a-certain-position)

Comment: can you please provide an input output example and what is the type of each variable?

Comment: I would say there probably isn’t a better way to do it, especially because the operation is so basic.

Answer (score 0):

USe the insert method of StringBuilder:

```
_sb.insert(0, "Hello ");
```