# Add spaces after 2 digits characters of a string in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

If i enter 5 digits or 6 digits or 7 digits character then I just want to add a space after 2 digit or 3 digits or 4 digits character of a string. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

```
E.g. given "M11AE", I need "M1 1AE" as the result.
E.g. given "B338TH", I need "B33 8TH" as the result.
E.g. given "DN551PT", I need "DN55 1PT" as the result.


 postCodeEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
 int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
   count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

           if ((!s.toString().contains(" ") && s.length() > 5)) {
                s.insert(2, " ");
            }else if (!s.toString().contains(" ") && (s.length()>6)) {
                s.insert(3, " ");
            }else if (!s.toString().contains(" ") && (s.length()>7)) {
                s.insert(4, " ");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884353/how-to-insert-a-character-in-a-string-at-a-certain-position

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i used text watcher:

if ((!s.toString().contains(" ") && s.length() > 5)) {
                    s.insert(2, " ");
                }else if (!s.toString().contains(" ") && (s.length()>6)) {
                    s.insert(3, " ");
                }else if (!s.toString().contains(" ") && (s.length()>7)) {
                    s.insert(4, " ");
                }

Comment: Add this to your question, please, along with how you're using your TextWatcher and what behaviour your're seeing now

Comment: i add, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may not be the best answer, but it works. I took a `textview` and `edittext`. Next, I set the `edittext` font color to transparent. After that, I went to the java file and on the edittext, I set a text watcher. So whenever the user types something, your textwatcher gets the actual input. So depending on that, you modify the string and set the string on the `textview`. So this gives the desired illusion. 
Here is the partial `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the java code:

```
package com.applications.invisible;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView myTextView;
    EditText myEditTExt;
    String actualText;
    String visibleText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        myEditTExt = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

        myEditTExt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                actualText = myEditTExt.getText().toString();
                visibleText = myVisibleText(actualText);
                myTextView.setText(visibleText);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private String myVisibleText(String actualText) {
        String ret = "";
        if(actualText.length() == 5){
            ret = actualText.substring(0,2)+" "+actualText.substring(2);
        }else if(actualText.length() == 6){
            ret = actualText.substring(0,3)+" "+actualText.substring(3);
        }else if(actualText.length() >= 7){
            ret = actualText.substring(0,4)+" "+actualText.substring(4);
        }else{
            ret = actualText;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: its working fine thank you so much for this logic i don't think this logic in my mind.