# Double manipulation trouble

Tags: java

Suppose n is a Double type variable .

```
double right=n-(Math.ceil(n)-1);

//Here I am trying to get the right part of the number.
```

Now if `n=1234.78`

then `right=0.7799999999999727`

why not `.78`?

and when

```
n=1234.89
```

then `right=0.8900000000001`

why not `89`? and why not `9999`... here instead of `000000`....?

Now suppose I want to find the sum of digits in right..Like in my example for 1234.89 its 8+9=17 or 1234.781 its 7+8+1-16. So then ?what should I do?

But I can't do it using floating point arithmatic?Like

```
double temp=0.0; 
while(right>0) 
{ 
right=rigth*10; 
temp=Math.floor(right); 
right=right-temp; 
suml+=temp; 
}
```

in kind of a way I mentioned above?
I am new to java. please explain my problem. It would be a great help for me. Thank you.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not 100% accurate, i.e. `0.1` can't be represented exactly. If you need 100% accuracy you can use `BigInteger` or `int`

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, if you are just interested in the decimal part: double right = n % 1; is in my opinion simpler way.

Comment: Possible dublicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the following code

```
    double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
                DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
    }
right=roundTwoDecimals(right);
    System.out.println(right);
```

You will get desired result.

Comment: Now suppose I want to find the sum of digits in right..Like in my example for 1234.89 its 8+9=17 or 1234.781 its 7+8+1-16. So then ?what should I do?

Comment: What is your exact requirement ? Getting sum of decimals after right or correcting it to 2 decimals.

Comment: Get substring from . to end. 
Convert that String to integer, iterate it into loop and add the values.

Comment: Thank you..But I can't do it using floating point arithmatic?Like

double temp=0.0;
while(right>0)
{
right=rigth*10;
temp=Math.floor(right);
right=right-temp;
suml+=temp;
}

in kind of a way I mentioned above?

Comment: @ArijitSaha I suppose that approach should work.Please share your errors/expected and output obtained

Answer (score 0):

floating point works the same in almost all languages and you see the same issues.  If you want the fractional part you should use.

```
double fract = n - (long) n;
```

I suspect the formula you are using will not work for negative numbers. (and is slower)

This can produce a rounding error as you have seen so you need to chose a level of precision.  You might choose 2 or 6 digits.  You can round the value when you calculate it but it's often simpler to round it when you print it.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", fract);
```

This will print `0.78` and `0.89` as you expect.