# Java: Combination function yields decimal number

Tags: java, double, combinations

I was trying to implement a simple combination function

```
private int combination(int n, int k)
{
    if(n>>1 < k)
        k = n - k;
    double mul = 1;
    for(int i=n+1-k;i<n+1;i++)
        mul *= i;
    for(int i=k;i>0;i--)
        mul /= i;
    return (int)mul;
}
```

When I feed in parameters as `combination(33,17)`, it gives me **1166803109**, though the correct number should be **1166803110**. So I printed out the `mul` variable before truncating to int, and it gives me a decimal number: **1.1668031099999998E9**, which is confusing to me. By definition it should be a perfect division, why it gives me a decimal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). To avoid this problem maybe start using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to floating-point types like `float` or `double`, there's rarely perfect division (perfect in the sense that the floating-point result is a whole number).  This is because of the way that the values are represented internally; there is some loss of precision when the computation is carried out.  (It's similar to why the division `2/3` will be rendered by computers as `0.666667`.)  Rather than use `double`, stick with an integral type like `int` or `long`, or else use `BigInteger` or similar if your computation might reach values larger than a `long` can hold.

Answer (score 1):

Due to their  [internal representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_number#Internal_representation), Floating point arithmetic is not entirely accurate.

Since you are only interested in an integer representation of the result, you can round the double, instead of truncating, with `Math.round()`

Your method should become like this:

```
private int combination(int n, int k)
{
    if(n>>1 < k)
        k = n - k;
    double mul = 1;
    for(int i=n+1-k;i<n+1;i++)
        mul *= i;
    for(int i=k;i>0;i--)
        mul /= i;
    return (int) Math.round(mul);
}
```

Output:

```
System.out.println(combination(33,17));

1166803110
```

Comment: `Math.round` is not the best solution here.  In edge cases it could pick the wrong way to round and introduce subtle accuracy bugs.  Use an integral type for `mul` rather than a floating point type.

Comment: @Alanyst Can you think of any example of this case?

Comment: In the case where the algorithm ensures that the the divisor is a factor of the dividend, it probably won't happen.  So, the fear of accuracy problems using `Math.round` is probably unfounded, and you're right to question me on that.  However, I think it's still the less optimal choice; integral values are much faster to compute than floating-point values that are then coerced to integral values using a rounding computation.

Comment: Ok leaving the answer here in case OP does not want to change the footprint of his method.