# Why a sum of Double.parseDouble of EditText return a little different value?

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
try {
    Ciocco_V.tot = Double.parseDouble(Et444Tot.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    Ciocco_V.burro = Double.parseDouble(Et111Burro.getText().toString()); 
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    Ciocco_V.fibra = Double.parseDouble(Et222Fibra.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and inside the edittex there are this number:

44.2(burro) and 40.6(fibra) 84.8(tot)

```
if (((Ciocco_V.burro + Ciocco_V.fibra) != Ciocco_V.tot ) {
    //fail condition
} else {
   // correct
}
```

if I inspect the condition **Ciocco_V.burro + Ciocco_V.fibra** return this value:
84.80000000000001
and my IF fail....
why?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of floating point precision. It is better practice to compare the two like this:

```
if (((Ciocco_V.burro + Ciocco_V.fibra) - Ciocco_V.tot) > 0.00000001 ){

    //fail condition
}else{
   // correct
}
```

Comment: this is too much approsimative in this contidion ((Ciocco_V.burro + Ciocco_V.fibra) - Ciocco_V.tot) > 0.00000001) the return value is:
1.4210854715202004E-14, 
I have modify the if condition like this:
if(( Math.abs((Ciocco_V.burro + Ciocco_V.fibra) - Ciocco_V.tot) > 0.00000001) 
and this work well.

Comment: Yeah my answer wasnt tested. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you did a little research you could come by this: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15724087/1470496)

This questions is asked many times before!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Double.compare(d1, d2)` to compare the two values:

```
 int retval = Double.compare(Ciocco_V.burro + Ciocco_V.fibra, Ciocco_V.tot);
 if (retval != 0) {

 }
```

it returns

> the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if
>   d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is
>   numerically greater than d2.

Comment: this fail same as my IF

Comment: Probably because the sum of the two values give you the total and you are checking for != when you should check for ==