# print double number in java and get wrong answer

Tags: java, double, println

```
double check =0.615 * 255 -0.515 * 255 -0.100 * 255;
System.out.println(check);
```

why get -2.8421709430404007E-14? it should be 0.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/177512/887149 see this post

Comment: @JunedAhsan because when you use calculation to calculate it should be 0,cause 156.825-131.325-25.5=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double operation has some precision problem. Use BigDecimal operation instead of double than you will get expected result.

```
  //double check =0.615 * 255 + -0.515 * 255 + -0.100 * 255;
   BigDecimal check =
             (BigDecimal.valueOf(0.615).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(255)))
            .add(BigDecimal.valueOf( -0.515).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf( 255)))
            .add(BigDecimal.valueOf( -0.100).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf( 255)));

  System.out.println(check);
```

**Result is : 0.000**

Answer (score 2):

Debugging your math:

```
double check0 = 0.615 * 255;
System.out.println(check0);
double check1 = -0.515 * 255;
System.out.println(check1);
double check3 = -0.100 * 255;
System.out.println(check3);
System.out.println("Result: " + (check0 + check1 + check3));
```

Output:

```
156.825
-131.32500000000002
-25.5
Result: -2.8421709430404007E-14
```

Remember that:

- multiplication has higher operator priority than addition in Java
- you should use `BigDecimal` if you want control over the rounding
  when performing operations with floating point numbers

Comment: but check2 should be 131.325  but not 131.3250000000002

Comment: @Rebecca that's exactly why you want to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double` in this case. Also check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java) SO page to get started on the hows and whys.

Comment: BigDecimal is the answer, thanks!!!