# Losing precision converting from double to int in Java

Tags: java, precision

I tried to test the following code, and it gave me a 434 on n, the result which I did not anticipate, what's the reason for this loss of precision?

```
double f = 4.35;
int n =  (int) (100 * f); // n will be 434 - why?
n = (int) Math.round(100*f); // n will be 435
```

Comment: Because 4.35 is not exactly representable by a `double`.  Welcome to floating point.

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I see a double variable initialized to some value like 21.4 as 21.399999618530273?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point isn't perfect. It uses approximated values.

In particular, `double`s can not represent all numbers. Just like `1/3` can't be precisely represented in decimal using a finite number of digits, so too can't `4.35` be represented in binary with a finite number of bits.

So we get *rounded* results. Values that are *close* to `4.35`, but not quite equal.
In this case, it's a bit smaller, so when you multiply it by 100, you don't get `435`, you get *almost 435*, which is not quite the same.

When you cast to `int`, you truncate the result, so `434,999...` becomes just `434`.

In contrast, when you use `Math.round`, you convert `434,999...` to exactly `435` (which *can* be represented precisely).

If precisely representing `4.35` is necessary, take a look at Java [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) type.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point cannot represent exactly the floating-point number.

You can try printing it, you'll see that `100 * f = 434.9999999`. The `int` value for that double will be `434` as it is truncating the decimal part.

The `round` method will round to the closest `int` number, which is `435`.

Comment: thank you for your answer! why is 100 * f = 434.999999 not 435?

Comment: @user133466 as roioppi said, the floating point has a limitation. Floating point numbers cannot be exactly represented.

Comment: Because 'f' wasn't 4.35 in the first place. @roioppi already told you that.