# How do I convert decimal 75.95 to 7595 in Java?

Tags: java, converters

I have a program in which i need to convert `double 75.95` to normal integer `7595`. How do I write the actual program?

My code is:

```
class test5 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       double d = 75.95;
       System.out.println("Price before converting = "+d);
       int i = (int)d;
       System.out.println("(float)d = "+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you want to do with 75.9?

Comment: `(int)(d * 100)` ?

Comment: i need that 75.95 to be done into 7595 directly my text book question is this:

Write a program to read the price of an item in decimal form (like 75.95) and print the output in paise (like 7595 paise)...

Comment: Hey alfasin thanks i got the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Any particular reason why multiplying by 100 wouldn't work?

```
class test5 {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        double d = 75.95;
        System.out.println("Price before converting = "+d);
        long i = Math.round(d * 100);
        System.out.println("(float)d = "+i);
    }
}
```

You have to be careful with rounding errors. See: [Losing precision converting from int to double in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214559/losing-precision-converting-from-int-to-double-in-java)

Comment: `Math.round` returns a `long` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Now my code is this and its working :) thanks all of you :)

```
class test5
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double d = 75.95;
        {
            System.out.println("Price before converting = "+d);
            int i = (int)(d*100);
            System.out.println("Answer after converting = "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will lose the values after decimal.... I.e. For 75.95, it will give 7500 as output... Which is not correct... Kindly review your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply by a constant 100 (if there are only, and always two decimal points). If there are more, you could use `String.valueOf(double)` and remove the '.' and call a `double` a `double` (not a `float`). Something like

```
double d = 75.95;
// int val = (int) (d * 100); // <-- or this.
String str = String.valueOf(d).replace(".", "");
int val = Integer.valueOf(str);
System.out.printf("(double)%f = (int)%d%n", d, val);
```

Which outputs

```
(double)75.950000 = (int)7595
```