# Error in calculating sum of rows

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtable, sum

[image]

Can anyone please explain why this happen? If i get SQL sum its total correct. My code is below.

```
private void calTotalSMV() {

    double ttl_smv = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < OBJ_CALLER.DTMEMERG.getRowCount(); x++) {
        ttl_smv += Double.parseDouble(OBJ_CALLER.DTMEMERG.getValueAt(x, 3).toString());
        System.out.println("total smv = " + ttl_smv);
    }
    jLabel23.setText("" + ttl_smv);
}
```

Comment: See StackOverflow Questions:

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996">Why do I see a double variable initialized to some value like 21.4 as 21.399999618530273?</a>

or
<br/>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java">Retain precision with Doubles in java</a>

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error, it's all about precision for floating point numbers(float, double).If you want more accurate results, use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Easier solutions would be rounding([Math.round](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) function) and formatting([NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)).