# GWT DoubleBox value changes on focus in and focus out

Tags: java, gwt

One DoubleBox is there on page when I focus in on that box the value of the box is getting changed only for the first time on loading particular page.Below is the line of code which acts strangely.Is this known issue?

m_editablePropertyValue.setValue( DoubleTextBoxCell.this.getValue() );

for example if value in double box is 100.10000001 and if I focus in then value becomes 100.10000001001 and this issue is only for displaying the value.If I save this page the original value only getting saved

Comment: Can any one help? Need any more details?

Comment: I think, that this problem is caused by the inaccuracy of doubles (More info here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996)). You could try to use a formatter for displaying the double-value -> `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat`