# Java big decimal number format exception

Tags: java, exception, bigdecimal

Why does the code below throw a java number format exception?

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("10934,375");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that constructor of `BigDecimal` requires decimal number format where decimals come right after decimal dot `.` instead of decimal comma `,` so the right format for this specific case would be:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("10934.375");
```

Comment: Great, you asked the question and answered it instantly. Why is that so?

Comment: To share information maybe? It took me pretty long to resolve the problem in my code.

Comment: @Octopus: [self-answering a question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) [is encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to?rq=1).

Comment: That's very nice to hear :) You got my upvote for your question and answer. I also learnt that *German Locale uses comma for decimal points instead of dot*

Comment: @Octopus Most European countries do, except for the Brits. My own country doesn't have a constant in Locale. Examples: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for the link, Cheers! BTW, which is your country?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the `BigDecimal` class does not take any `Locale` into account in its constructor that takes a `String`, as can be read in the Javadoc of this constructor:

> the fraction consists of a decimal point followed by zero or more
>   decimal digits.

If you want to parse according to a different `Locale`, one that uses the comma as decimals separator, you need to use `java.text.DecimalFormat` with a specific `Locale`.

Example:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.0", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN));
fmt.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal n = (BigDecimal) fmt.parse("10934,375");
```

*Note*: you need to get an instance of `DecimalFormat` (a subclass of `NumberFormat`) to be able to call the method `setParseBigDecimal`. Otherwise it returns a `Double` instead, which is a binary floating point number, and binary floating point numbers [cannot accurately represent many decimal fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996). So that would cause a loss of accuracy in many cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use NumberFormat to choose the Locale, see the example:

```
        String numberToFormat = "1.900,35";
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        Number number = formatter.parse(numberToFormat);
        BigDecimal decimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(number.doubleValue());
```

Comment: As i understand clearly, This will cause a loss of precision since `double` cannot accurately represent many decimal fractions. Please correct me if i am not

Comment: Conversion to double indeed loses **accuracy**

Comment: You're correct to call it accuracy instead of precision (in the scientific sense). I've updated my answer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision