# How can I retrieve double value from custom jtextfield

Tags: java, swing

I have create a custom JTextFields that can accept only number values.

So I have this:

```
package com.mcsolution.common.Componenti_Swing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import com.mcsolution.common.supporto.VisualMessage;


public class DoubleTextFieldFormat extends TextFieldFormat{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8856130645860365803L;
    public DoubleTextFieldFormat(){
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char ch = e.getKeyChar();

                if (!isNumber(ch) && !isValidSignal(ch) && !validatePoint(ch)  && ch != '\b') {
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public DoubleTextFieldFormat(Font font,Boolean isSelectedAll,Integer horizzontalAlignment,
            Integer numberCharacter,String text,Dimension preferredSize,
            Boolean isEditable){

        if(font!=null)
            this.setFont(font);

        if(isSelectedAll){
            this.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
                    selectAll();
                }
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){
                }
            });
        }
        if(horizzontalAlignment!=null)
            this.setHorizontalAlignment(horizzontalAlignment);

        if(numberCharacter!=null)
            this.setDocument(new PersonalizzaJtextField(numberCharacter));

        if(text!=null)
            this.setText(text);
        if(preferredSize!=null)
            this.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);

        if(isEditable!=null)
            this.setEditable(isEditable);

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char ch = e.getKeyChar();

                if (!isNumber(ch) && !isValidSignal(ch) && !validatePoint(ch)  && ch != '\b') {
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isNumber(char ch){
        return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
    }

    private boolean isValidSignal(char ch){
        if( (getText() == null || "".equals(getText().trim()) ) && ch == '-'){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean validatePoint(char ch){
        if(ch != '.'){
            return false;
        }

        if(getText() == null || "".equals(getText().trim())){
            setText("0.");
            return false;
        }else if("-".equals(getText())){
            setText("-0.");
        }

        return true;
    }

    public Double getValue(){
        try{
            String valore = this.getText();
            valore= valore.replaceAll(",", ".");
            return Double.parseDouble(valore);
        }catch(Exception e){
            VisualMessage.getErrore();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I want retrieve the value I use this code:

```
Double val = myTextField.getValue();
```

This method works not every times.

For example if I have this value into TextField 1.900,50 if have an errore.

How can I convert the value in this format x.xxx,xx?

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener` to filter a text component, use a a `DocumentFilter` instead.  See [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details.

Comment: You should use either a `JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField` as they already provide this functionality. See [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more details

Comment: Personally, I'd remove the formatting (`,`) and then rely on `Double.parseDouble`

Comment: is 1.900,50 a valid number format? Number separator after the decimal point?

Comment: yes, and @MadProgrammer I can't remove (,) because this character is decimal separator

Comment: @bircastri Not to a `double` it isn't.  You're confusing the "format" with the "value"

Comment: how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java big decimal number format exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454133/java-big-decimal-number-format-exception)

Comment: You are using a number in a European (probably Italian, considering your profile) locale. Don't use `Double.parseDouble` because it expects something very close to the US locale. See the answer I voted as a duplicate of this question. Instead of Locale.GERMAN, use Locale.ITALIAN (although the German Locale can also parse numbers in your format). And in that case, don't replace the comma with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my error, I have change my getValue() method with this:

```
public Double getValue(){
    try{
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        //String valore = ;
        return nf.parse(this.getText()).doubleValue();

    }catch(Exception e){
        VisualMessage.getErrore();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So now your code only works for ITALIAN locale (and similar). What about using Locale.default to support the users setting. Haven't looked into your code to see if this is the only thing needed to support all locales.