# Why does this precision fail example show up with doubles but not with floats?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, floating-point-precision

There's a great discussion on SO about why floating-point should not be used for currency operations and a lovely example is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency/3730249#3730249) from Bloch's Effective Java.

I was playing around with this and noticed something weird. If the numbers are doubles:

```
System.out.println(1.03d - .42d); 
//prints out 0.6100000000000001.
```

But, if the numbers are floats:

```
System.out.println(1.03f - .42f); 
//prints out 0.61.
```

Why does this not fail in the same way for floats also? Both types are susceptible to the same problem, but what causes the difference in behaviour?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996 .  And although this is referring to C#, the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/q/618535/509840 are superb.

Comment: Why should it? Floats are less precise than doubles.

Comment: every single value will behave differently between floats and doubles because of their binary representation, one example of properly displayed float is not an example that every float will be fine

Comment: @EJP right, they are less precise, but I'm not sure I understand why that matters here.

Comment: @KamilMikolajczyk Of course not all floats would be fine. But the question is why is this one fine at all?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu you would have to see their binary representations, do the binary substraction and see where's the difference, it probably comes from rounding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are eight interesting values involved here (four for each type). Their exact values are:

**Double values**

```
1.03d:  1.0300000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875
0.42d:  0.419999999999999984456877655247808434069156646728515625
Result: 0.6100000000000000976996261670137755572795867919921875
0.61d:  0.60999999999999998667732370449812151491641998291015625
```

**Float values**

```
1.03f:  1.0299999713897705078125
0.42f:  0.4199999868869781494140625
Result: 0.61000001430511474609375
0.61f:  0.61000001430511474609375
```

Note how the closest `double` to 1.03 is slightly *more* than 1.03, and the closest double to 0.42 is slightly *less* than 0.42... so the result of the subtraction differs from the precise (decimal) subtraction by the sum of those two errors.

The closest `float` to 1.03 and the closest `float` to 0.42 are both less than the original values, so the errors mitigate against each other to some extent. That's why the `double` result "feels" more inaccurate than the `float` result. The `float` result happens to be as close to 0.61 as you can represent as a `float`, so the string representation is just "0.61". As there *is* a closer `double` to 0.61 than the subtraction result, the string representation has to differentiate between the two.