# VBA - all excel sum functions doesn't work properly

Tags: vba, excel

what's the issue? because of some strange reasons excel can't sum properly values from ranges.

### please look in the

[image]

the proper sum of presented range is `0`, excel tells that it sums to `1,818989E-12`. when i select minor range (e.g. without first or last cell), it sums properly, when i change numberformat of range, it sums properly - but those workarounds works only in worksheet - when i use VBA (and actually this is a part of some macro) i'm still getting this strange number - every single `WorksheetFunction` like `Sum`, `Subtotal`, `SumIf` still returning inproper result, changing of numberformat of range doesn't work, multiplying by 1 also, so any suggestions will be welcome. i can tell also that this happens only in this specific case - probably the rest of analyzed data are fine (=sum works properly), also this is not a variable type issue, because first version of code didn't use any variable to mark the sum.

here's the part of code:

```
For Each kom In amountRng
    Set baza = Rows("" & prevKom.Offset(1, 0).Row & ":" & kom.Offset(-1, 0).Row & "")
    baza.Copy
    Sheets("roboczy").Activate
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'multipying by 1 doesn't work
    'Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
    'Selection.Value = 1
    'Selection.Copy
    'Range(Range("V2"), Range("V2").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply

    'changing of numberformat doesn't work
    'Columns("V:V").NumberFormat = "0.00"

        If IsEmpty(Range("A3")) Then
            Range("M2").Copy
            Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else:
            Range(Range("M2"), Range("M2").End(xlDown)).Copy
            Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Selection.RemoveDuplicates 1
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

    Dim liczba As Single

    For Each zam In Selection
        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:=zam.Value
        Set sumowanieRng = Range(Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp), Range("V2")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        sumowanieRng.EntireRow.Copy
        liczba = WorksheetFunction.Sum(sumowanieRng)
        Debug.Print liczba
            If liczba = 0 Then
                Sheets("zerowe").Activate
                Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Else:
                Sheets("niezerowe").Activate
                Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheets("roboczy").Activate
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    Range(Range("A2"), Selection).EntireRow.Clear
    Sheets(2).Activate
    Set prevKom = kom
Next
```

Comment: Look into SUbtotal(), you are using sum() and that may include the hidden columns

Comment: Hasn't this been discussed here a couple of times? It is [floating point arithmetic error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113).

Comment: [See this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996/177539#177539).

Comment: thank you guys, sorry for duplicate the question. didn't hear earlier about floating points so i even didn't know what i should look for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more accurate summation use a non-floating point data type like decimal

```
Dim d, c, i

For Each c In Range("B2:B25")
    d = d + CDec(c)
    i = i + CDbl(c)
Next c
Debug.Print d, i
```

Outputs

```
 0             1.81898940354586E-12
```

Keep in mind 1.81898940354586E-12 is VERY close to 0.