# Adding two decimal numbers Hive SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hiveql

I am trying to add two numbers using Hive SQL.

```
select 4.6 + 3.1 from <table> => 7.699999999999999
```

But,

```
select 4.7 +3.2 from <table>  => 7.9
```

I understand that *rounding* of result will give the expected output but the question is why this different behavior in first place?

I am using hive 2.11 (hive context) with Apache spark 1.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have observed is not Hive specific. Example:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
>>> 4.7+3.2
7.9
>>> 4.6+3.1
7.699999999999999
```

It's related to how the double numbers are stored in memory in some languages (floating-point):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation

See also:

- [Why do I see a double variable initialized to some value like 21.4 as 21.399999618530273?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Sorry about delay!. Thanks for answering. Accepted.